# STL bitset problem

Tags: c++, header-files, bitsets

I have a template class **"HEADER_FILE"** that has a variable bitset<>

```
using std::bitset<REG_SIZE>;
using std::bitset<REG_SIZE_2>;

template <int regSize=REG_SIZE>class Foo{
    bitset<regSize> bits;
};
```

i cannot use

```
using namespace std;
```

in header file which however is not giving any errors.

**error: template_id cannot appear in a using statement.**

where am i going wrong ;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
using std::bitset;
```

instead. Even better, change to:

```
template <int regSize=REG_SIZE>class Foo{
    std::bitset<regSize> bits;
};
```

because polluting the global scope in headers is not a kind thing to do.